# Need more context for the Grafanalib Python3 library

Tags: python, json, grafana, display

I'm building a project using python and grafana where I'd like to generate a certain number of copies of certain grafana dashboards based on certain criteria.  I've downloaded the grafanalib library to help me out with that, and I've read through the [Generating Dashboards From Code](https://grafanalib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started.html#generating-dashboards-from-code) section of the grafanalib website, but I feel like I still need more context to understand how to use this library.

So my first question is, how do I convert a [grafana dashboard JSON model](https://github.com/Secretasianman77/GG-Project-/blob/34600b8ec62cd08d33ca2787264736da38935355/Grafana%20JSON%20Model) into a python friendly format?  What method of organization do I use?  I saw the dashboard generation function written in the grafanalib documentation, but it looked quite a bit different from how my JSON data is organized.  I'd just like some further description of how to do the conversion.

My second question is, once I've converted my grafana JSON into a python format, how do I then get the proper information to send that generated dashboard to my grafana server?  I see in the grafanalib documentation the "upload_to_grafana" function used to send the information and it takes in the three parameters (json, server, api_key), and I understand where its getting the json parameter from, but I dont get where the server information or API key are coming from or where that information is found to be input.

This is all being developed on a raspberry pi 4 just to put that out there.  I'm working on a personal smart agriculture project as a way to develop my coding abilities further, as I'm self taught.  Any help that can be provided to help me in my understanding is most appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

create an API key in Grafana configuration ..The secret key that u get while creating is the API key ..Server is localhost:3000 in case of installed grafana

Comment: Welcome! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and improve your answer (add link to docs, for example).